# Is it possible to write dirty flags with ref getters?

Tags: c#, struct, mutable

Is it possible to write dirty flags with ref returned get only properties in C#?

```cs
    public class ByRef<T> where T : struct
    {
        private bool _dirty;
        private T    _value;

        public ref T Value
        {
            get
            {
                var oldValue = _value;
                Task.Run(() => //Possible bad attempt at executing code after return.
                {
                    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1));
                    if (!_value.Equals(oldValue))
                    {
                        _dirty = true;
                    }
                });
                return ref _value;
            }
        }

        public bool Dirty
        {
            get => _dirty;
            set => _dirty = value;
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public class Node2D : Node
    {
        private ByRef<          float   > _rotation;
        private ByRef<(float X, float Y)> _position;
        private ByRef<(float X, float Y)> _scale;

        public ref           float    Rotation => ref _rotation.Value;
        public ref (float X, float Y) Position => ref _position.Value;
        public ref (float X, float Y) Scale    => ref _scale   .Value;
        
        protected override void OnUpdate(NodeEventArgs args)
        {
            if (_rotation.Dirty || _position.Dirty || _scale.Dirty)
            {
                //Update
            }
        }
```

The main reason I want to do this is to allow mutable members in the tuples so I can modify X and Y separately.

I also don't want to be updating position, rotation and scale every frame, so I was wondering if its possible to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: Why in blazes is the `ByRef<>.Value` getter spinning up a `Task`?!  Just to check if its dirty or not?  Surely it's much more efficient to set `_dirty` in the setter?  Also, I would hate to run your code in the debugger as it will most likely spam `Task`s if you just happened to have an instance of `Node2D` in the **Autos**, **Locals** or **Watch** windows

Comment: @MickyD Its to check for modification to set the dirty flag. also ref properties can't have setters and even if they could the value can be mutated and directly assigned to since its a ref

Comment: Is there a point to those two tasks?

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes so I can both have mutable X and Y components and have a dirty flag

Comment: Although I'm sure this does what you intend to for now, the kind of logic in ref Value will lead to unexpected behavior and race conditions. Could you also elaborate what you are having trouble with. The title provides only a general sense of the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: @Shadowblitz16 _"Its to check for modification to set the dirty flag. also ref properties can't have setters and even if they could the value can be mutated and directly assigned to since its a ref"_ - don't use `ref`.  I think you have gotten into this predicament due to a **problem of design**

Comment: @MickyD I don't see the design problem many other languages allow mutating components of a struct specifically things like vectors (not talking about c++ std::vectors). If there is a better way to do it in C# I'm all ears.

Comment: @DekuDesu I did have a suspicion about using Task to do such a thing. it really if a awful workaround.

Comment: Have you considered changing value to be an Auto Property with a private backing field, and any time the values set property is accessed check to see if the value was changed? `T Value { get => _Value; set { if(value.Equals(_Value) is false) { Dirty=true; } _Value = value; } } bool Dirty {get; private set;}`

Comment: _"Its to check for modification to set the dirty flag... **I don't see the design problem**"_ - so if `Value` is only updated _once per second_ and the rest of your code merely reads it _once per millisecond_ you'll be spinning up **1,000 `Tasks` over a 1 second interval**.  So there's that

Comment: @DekuDesu Yes but that makes the struct members immutable because I would be accessing the struct by value in the property getter. so no MyByRefVar.Value.X = someNumber.

Comment: @MickyD yes I agree with the Task part it was just a naive example of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to write dirty flags with ref returned get only properties in C#?

It sure is, and technically you did successfully implement something that does exactly that.

That being said however, spinning up a `Task`, having it dispatched by the `TaskScheduler`, and checking if the value was changed is opens yourself to many issues.

Normally I would not opine on *implementation details* if they work. But the way you implemented this feature **will** lead to race conditions and *unexpected behavior* which can either cause catastrophic bugs for your users and/or very difficult to debug timings and other synchronization issues down the line.

For the small price of an additional backing field we can eliminate the `TaskScheduler` completely.

To implement this change you have to understand how the CLR handles by `ref` value types. When you say for example:

```cs
ref x = ref node.Rotation;
```

what you're essentially saying is, *"Go to `node`, then go to property `Rotation`then go to field `_rotation`, return the managed memory address where `_rotation` is stored."*

This allows you to have a mutable struct in the same storage location, which it sounds like is your intention.

With this knowledge we can derive a fairly reliable way to give them the `&address` and check to see if they changed the value at the `&address`. We can pull this off with another backing field to store a copy of what was at that `&address` when we gave it to them. Later, if we want to know if the object is 'dirty' we just compare the current value at the `&address` with what we stored earlier. If they are different, we know for a fact that the caller changed the value at the `&address` we gave them. (This is assuming no other callers are accessing it at the same time, if that was the case, we would know if it changed, but not which caller changed it, among other quirks with managed memory).

```cs
public class ByRef<T> where T : struct
{
    private T _value;
    private T oldValue;

    public ref T Value
    {
        get
        {
            // since the address to the backing field is being accessed we should store a copy of the value of the
            // backing field before it was accessed, so in the future, if dirty is checked, we can determine
            // if the value in the backing field has changed
            oldValue = _value;
            return ref _value;
        }
    }

    public bool Dirty => _value.Equals(oldValue) is false;

    // alternatively if you want the Dirty flag to auto-reset every time it's checked you could do
    public bool Dirty
    {
        get
        {
            bool wasDirty = _value.Equals(oldValue) is false;

            if (wasDirty)
            {
                // since it was dirty, we should now save the current value, so subsequent calls to .Dirty are false
                // this is optional, if this functionality is needed
                oldValue = _value;
            }

            return wasDirty;
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation might seem fairly simple but we can test the validity of the mutability of the backing field to obtain proof that the objects were mutated in-place wherever they are stored in managed memory. (This is ignoring that immutable structs may have been copied, altered, and re-placed into the same address by the CLR, but this shouldn't make a difference).

```cs
public class Node2D
{
    private ByRef<float> _rotation = new();
    private ByRef<(float x, float y)> _position = new();
    private ByRef<(float X, float Y)> _scale = new();

    public ref float Rotation => ref _rotation.Value;

    public ref (float x, float y) Position => ref _position.Value;

    public ref (float x, float y) Scale => ref _scale.Value;

    public void DumpInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Check Dirty Statuses of all Fields");
        Console.WriteLine($"Position ({_position.Dirty}) Rotation ({_rotation.Dirty}) Scale ({_scale.Dirty})");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

        Console.WriteLine($"Verifying the backing fields have not changed addresses and have not been moved by GC or CLR");
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (float* pointer = &_rotation.Value)
            {
                DumpAddress(nameof(Rotation), (long)pointer, _rotation.Value);
            }
            fixed ((float x, float y)* pointer = &_position.Value)
            {
                DumpAddress(nameof(Position), (long)pointer, _position.Value);
            }
            fixed ((float x, float y)* pointer = &_scale.Value)
            {
                DumpAddress(nameof(Scale), (long)pointer, _scale.Value);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    }
    private unsafe void DumpAddress(string Name, long pointer, object Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name}\n\r\t Address:{pointer:X} Value:{Value}");
    }
}
```

We can then use this to test that the fields are mutable, and we have up-to-date, **but not atomic**, information on if the values are different from the last time we checked.

```cs
// create a node
var node = new Node2D();

// dump initial info for comparison
node.DumpInfo();
/*
Position (False) Rotation (False) Scale (False)
Rotation
         Address: 1F440C8DF10 Value:0
Position
         Address: 1F440C8DF28 Value:(0, 0)
Scale
         Address: 1F440C8DF48 Value:(0, 0)
*/

// access field but do not change value
ref float x = ref node.Rotation;

_ = x * 2;

// check to make sure nothing changed
node.DumpInfo();
/*
Position (False) Rotation (False) Scale (False)
Rotation
         Address: 1F440C8DF10 Value:0
Position
         Address: 1F440C8DF28 Value:(0, 0)
Scale
         Address: 1F440C8DF48 Value:(0, 0)
*/

// change a single field
x = 12f;

// check to make sure the address is still the same, and the value changed
node.DumpInfo();
/*
Position (False) Rotation (True) Scale (False)
Rotation
         Address: 1F440C8DF10 Value: 12
Position
         Address: 1F440C8DF28 Value:(0, 0)
Scale
         Address: 1F440C8DF48 Value:(0, 0)
*/

// change the tuples to ensure they are mutable as well
node.Position.x = 1.22f;
node.Scale.y = 0.78f;

// check to make sure the address is still the same, and the value changed
node.DumpInfo();
/*
Position (True) Rotation (False) Scale (True)
Rotation
         Address:1F440C8DF10 Value:12
Position
         Address:1F440C8DF28 Value:(1.22, 0)
Scale
         Address:1F440C8DF48 Value:(0, 0.78)
*/

// this is optional, but check again to see if the dirty flags have cleared
node.DumpInfo();
/*
Position (False) Rotation (False) Scale (False)
Rotation
         Address:1F440C8DF10 Value:12
Position
         Address:1F440C8DF28 Value:(1.22, 0)
Scale
         Address:1F440C8DF48 Value:(0, 0.78)
*/
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for, thankyou.